# React/Redux: focus is lost in the input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, devextreme

When you enter text in the field, focus is lost. Why?

If remove the label prop, then the problem is solved. But a label is needed

```
<SimpleItem
  label={{ text: "Your Address" }}
  dataField="surname"
  editorOptions={{
    value: formEdit.surname,
    onValueChanged: ({ value }) => {
      addChange("surname", value);
    },
    valueChangeEvent: "keyup"
  }}
/>;
```

online demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/de-form-ezmmg

Comment: In general, where React is concerned, losing focus for inputs is caused by the input re-rendering, thereby it technically being a different element and so focus is lost. This is usually remedied by seeing what kind of re-renders happen during typing and making sure they're only occurring where needed, or giving the input elements keys so that they can be properly identified and persisted by React

Comment: Please show how to do this, using the example of this question. I do not understand why this happens if do not use the label prop :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that when using `Label` as child of `SimpleItem` (instead of prop), the input doesn't lose focus on keyup event (I tried digging in the docs, but I couldn't find a reason why this would happen):

```
<SimpleItem
  dataField="surname"
  editorOptions={{
    value: formEdit.surname,
    onValueChanged: ({ value }) => {
      addChange("surname", value);
    },
    valueChangeEvent: "keyup"
  }}
>
     <Label text="Your Address" />
</SimpleItem>
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/de-form-zwerw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Incredible, but it works great! 
Faced a problem, if a lot of data comes into the input fields, then this slows down during input. Maybe I didn’t set up the store correctly for working with forms?
Example:
http://g.recordit.co/TJudzIBo9l.gif

Comment: Are you doing any additional action on every keyup? maybe fetching data from server? I added many fields in the following [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/de-form-qm5vd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) and it doesn't have performance issue

Comment: All is well! 
I did not change label as child for all items, there were about two left. Therefore there were performance issues

Answer (score 0):

Well like what jaycee discuss your field is re-rendering whenever you keyup. I've tried to change the event to blur. Try this. I hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: are you try change field "Your name" yet?. Your change doesn't seem to like logical, when change value doesn't open SaveBar component.

Comment: No blur. Need to track for every change of character to display savebar. For example on keyup event